# Ubuntu/VNC: Too many "Too many security failures"

Tags: 12.04, vnc

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 server(s).  I use vncserver on them. Connection works for some time after launching the server. However, if I connect after few hours or about a day later,  I get "Too many security failures" error.   And in between, I do not make any unsuccessful / wrong password attempt.

This almost always happens and on multiple servers.

1) Could it be some bot trying to hack it? I could not find much in the log. In fact I could not find any info even of my own attempts in the logs. Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

2) When this happens, even waiting for some time does not work. I have to kill and start again - which often defeats the purpose of my VNC session.

Please help!

Regards,
JP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, there are scanning bots for popular vnc ports.
2. There is solution without killing vncserver: Connect by SSH, and type in command to change VNC password **vncpasswd** After changing password, authentication failures will reset and you'll be able to login again. In this case your VNC desktop will remain launched without interrupting.

Answer (score 0):

"VNC conenction failed: vncserver too many security failures"

Means that someone tried to log in with incorrect credentials too frequently within a specified period of time. What that number and time is vary depending on what VNC Server you're using.

Someone's probably running a script trying to log into anything it can find listening on the standard VNC ports, and you'll need to find out what ip this is coming from and block it.

Comment: Can you explain how to do that?

Comment: @KazWolfe you can find log in `/var/log/secure` files